# Computing id of html tag at runtime with keyup function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**What i am trying to do ?**

I want to format the jquery keyup function in such a way so that it will compute id of html tags at runtime by checking which input is currently under user control ( active ).

For example :

**html code :**

```
 <input id="first" />
 <input id="second" />
```

**jquery code:**

```
 $(if 'first' is active then it should be passed here).keyup(func_name);
```

thanks

Comment: $('#first').keyup(func_name);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you're trying to follow is not how jQuery (or JS itself) is designed to work.

A better idea would be to put a common class on both the elements, and then attach the event handler to that class. You can then use the `this` keyword to reference the element which raised the event within your `func_name()` function. Try this;

```js
$('.foo').keyup(func_name);

function func_name() {
  // your logic here...
  console.log(this.id, this.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="first" class="foo" />
<input id="second" class="foo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use comma separator for the both fields :

```
$('#first,#second').on('input', func_name);
```

**NOTE :** It's better to use `input` event when you track the user inputs in field.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#first,#second').on('input', func_name);

function func_name(){
  console.log(this.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="first" class='input-group'/>
<input id="second" class='input-group'/>
```